# Create a boot disc

Tags: live-usb

I am a beginner 
'Is there a questions already asked/answered page?
A friend gave me a boot able disc that allows me to surf undetected or not leave traces on my friends pc.
I just downloaded  ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 and was hoping to create a live boot disc.
Please forgive my ignorance
Thank you for your help

Comment: Any linux live disk will do the basics. "Surf undetected" is an oxymoron IMO you can mitigate surfing but you are always detectable. Google search linux privacy distros or see - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Netizen_Spin and http://www.techradar.com/news/software/security-software/10-of-the-best-linux-distros-for-privacy-fiends-and-security-buffs-1292902

Comment: As @bodhi.zazen said, there's no end-all-be-all "undetected" web browsing method. There are masking methods and minimal packet transfer, but there is always _something_ left behind.

Comment: The TOR website has information on privacy, but whole books are written on the subject. If packets return from a web server, or any other server, you are traceable, otherwise you could not communicate with "the internet" as packets would never return from the server.

Comment: I didn't finish
I appreciate your helping me learn>
I have so far to go but this is a great intro to what my friend said.
He said' if you have  a question that people in this network bend over backwards to respect the lack of knowledge or ignorance in the person asking.
and they really help you
Thank you again,
marquis

Answer (score 1):

There is something on the order of 1/4 million [active questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=active) here, the majority of which have answers, but a percentage still remain [unanswered](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

You can create a live boot disc with any software capable of burning an ISO image to disk. There are [several of these](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=iso+to+disk&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) many of which are Windows programs. Imgburn is known to work in Linux under wine. Linux options for this task are many but include [K3b](http://k3b.plainblack.com/download) and [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rufus](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/6062-rufus.html) to burn the iso image to a usb and boot using the pendrive

PS:- When using ubuntu live disks there are traces left behind
If u really want to become anonymous download [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/)  (The Amnesic Incognito live system) and burn it into a usb and follow the instructions

Comment: OP asked for a "boot disc"